# How can I get tokens in OAuth authorize in swift? Why I couldn't print "credential.oauthToken"?

Tags: api, oauth, token, credentials, keychain

### 1. Summarize the problem

I'm setting up a OAuth authorize in iPhone App. I want to get tokens by OAuth in swift. At first I couldn't success print(credential.oauthToken).

### 2. Provide background including what you've already tried

I already success to open OAuth page by jumpping to Safari. Maybe I could get a token already but I failed to print token and request API by oauthToken.

### 3. Show some code

```
import UIKit
import OAuthSwift
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import KeychainAccess
```

.. ..

```
let oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
    consumerKey:    "8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    consumerSecret: "7xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authorizeUrl:    "http://xxxxxx.com/oauth/authorize",
    accessTokenUrl: "http://xxxxxx.com/oauth/token",
    responseType:   "cxxxxx"
)
```

and

```
    @IBAction func onTappedSyncButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let keychain = Keychain(service: "myappname-token")
    oauthswift.accessTokenBasicAuthentification = true

    let handle = oauthswift.authorize(
        withCallbackURL: URL(string: "my-xxxxxx-app://samplesite")!,
            scope: "default", 
            state:"",
            success: { credential, response, parameters in
                // <<<<<<<<I can't get credential.oauthToken. why??<<<<<<
                print(credential.oauthToken)
                print("Sucesess")

                // I save a token by keychainAccess frameworks
                keychain["oauthToken"] = credential.oauthToken
        },
            failure: { error in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                print("Failed")
        }
        )
}
```

I failed print(credential.oauthToken) and print("Sucesess").

### 4. Describe expected and actual results

- Do I need a state:""?
  Maybe no. we don't need state everytime.
- Do I mistake saving to keychain?
  Maybe no. If I input keychain like below. I can succsess print and save in keycahin.

  ```
  do {
      try keychain.set("01234567", key: "oauthToken")
  } catch {
      print("aa")
  }
  ```
- Do I mistake code of oauthswift?
  Maybe no. I refer to official site of oauthswift.
  There is a example for Instagram by Authorize with OAuth2.0.
  https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift

Comment: I guess you don't want to store your auth token in UserDefaults, but in the `Keychain`.

Comment: what error do you receive in failure block?

Comment: Yes. I agree with you. It is better to save auth token in keychain rather than save in UserDefault.

Comment: Error Massage is nothing. I couldn't see print(credential.oauthToken) and print("Sucesess"). And there is no print("Failed").